# Python/Tkinter Event Argument Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

my code seems to run fine with the brown square appearing in the blank window until I try and press one of the keys, when I do that nothing happens apart from an error message appearing. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *

x, y, a, b = 50, 50, 100, 100
d = None

vel_dic = {
    "Left": ("left", -4, 0),
    "Right": ("right", 4, 0),
    "Down": ("down", 0, 4),
    "Up": ("up", 0, -4)}
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self):
        self.move
        self.x, self.y, self.a, self.b = 50, 50, 100, 100
        self.d = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(tk, height = 600, width = 600)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
        self.coord = [self.x, self.y, self.a, self.b]
        self.shape = self.canvas.create_rectangle(*self.coord, outline = "#cc9900", fill = "#cc9900")
    def move():
        if self.direction != 0:
            self.canvas.move(self.rect, self.xv, self.yv)
        tk.after(33, move)
    def on_keypress(event):
        self.direction, self.xv, self.yv = vel_dic[event.keysym]
    def on_keyrelease(event):
        self.direction = 0 

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("600x600")

sprite1 = Sprite()

tk.bind_all('<KeyPress>', sprite1.on_keypress)
tk.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', sprite1.on_keyrelease)
```

Error message when I press the right arrow key:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 137, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: on_keypress() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 137, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: on_keyrelease() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling to function inside an object, `self` (the instance of the object) is sent as a first argument. You can undo that with some methods, `staticmethod` as the most common one, but that is not what you look for in that case.

The error you get indicates the interpreter sent this `self` parameter and the regular `event` parameter, but your method gets only one parameter, and can not handle them.

Make sure all your functions gets `self` (or any name you choose like `inst`) as a first parameter in addition to the other parameters:

```
def on_keyrelease(self, event):
```

Same goes for `move` and `on_keypress`.

Comment: Thanks very much, it removed the error. However the code still doesn't move the square. Can you see the problem?

Comment: Your class does not inherit a tkinter `Frame` or `Widget`, and the properties names are broken. Take a look at this thread for oop tkinter - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/6575931

Comment: At no point do you ever actually call the ``move()`` method, so of course it doesn't move.  You're also not consistently naming your variables - ``self.d``  vs. ``self.direction``, ``self.shape`` v.s ``self.rect``.