# Python/Tkinter Lambda Event Argument Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to call the function showframe which takes two aurgument. When i call it from Button command in HomePage it shows an error. ***TypeError: showframe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'frame_name'*.** I can't understand why? As I called by class name so it should automatically get self, then frame_name will get the SignIn class. But thats not happening.

```
class Culpture(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        fhome = HomePage(root)
        fsignin = SignIn(root)
        self.showframe(fhome)
        fhome.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        fsignin.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def showframe(self, frame_name):
        frame_name.tkraise()
class HomePage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text="Homepage").grid()
        Button(self, text='SignIn', command=lambda: Culpture.showframe(SignIn), width=20).grid()
```

If I do this way,

`Button(self, text='SignIn', command=lambda: Culpture.showframe(parent, SignIn), width=20).grid()`

then it shows another error message.***TypeError: tkraise() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'*** So I tried to look some question I got one which is close to my solution[Python/Tkinter Event Argument Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653369/python-tkinter-event-argument-issue)
 but not same. If I try another way
`Button(self, text='SignIn', command=lambda: Culpture.showframe(parent, SignIn(parent)), width=20).grid()` then it shows no error but button does not open the new frame.

```
class SignIn(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    Label(self, text="SignIn").grid()
    Button(self, text='Submit', width=20).grid()
```

So it would be really helpfull if any of you can help me out.

Comment: what is `SignIn`?

Comment: That doesn't give an error and also it doesn't open signin frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things the wrong way. Ideally, you are supposed to make different classes for different pages which will make the code less messy.

So, make a different class for SignIn and a different one for home.

Following is written in python3:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Culpture(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    F1=tk.Frame(self)
    F1.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)

    F1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    F1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.frames={}

    for F in (Home,SignIn):                                       # Looping between the pages: Home, SignIn (if they are interconnected through buttons)
        frame=F(F1,self)                                          # If they are all not interconnected, make different loops for different sets all containg the same element Home

        self.frames[F]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")


    self.show_frame(Home)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

    frame=self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class Home(tk.Frame):                                                   # Home page

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    label=Label(self,text="Home",foreground="blue")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    signB=Button(self,text="SignIn",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(SignIn),foreground="snow", background="blue")

    signB.pack()
    #trajectory.tkinter.tix.balloon



class SignIn(tk.Frame):                                                # SignIn

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label=Label(self,text="Enter datails",foreground="red")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    home=Button(self,text="Home",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Home),foreground="snow", background="red")
    home.pack()


root=Culpture()

root.mainloop()
```

Let me know, if this does not work.
Also,to add more pages:

If they are interconnected-    add the names of the classes to the same loop.

If they are connected to some page in common-  make a new lop, with the names.

Comment: `import tkinter as tk` & `from tkinter import *`... why?

Comment: In some very rare cases, when the program is very large, you may need it for organisation. It's not mandatory at all. I just do it for most of my programs to avoid errors (unless it lags..).

Comment: This code works. But I can't understand why I have to inherit Tk() class in Culpture instead of Frame class? Though I use a dictionary for frame class why I passed frames class in showframe `self.show_frame(Home)` instead of dictionary name?

Comment: @AbdullahAlMubin: you don't have to inherit from the `Tk` class. You can inherit from `Frame` instead. It's just that you have to have an instance of `Tk` somewhere, and since this is the "main" frame, there's no need to create a frame and then place it in an empty window.

Comment: @EshitaShukla Can you explain though using a dictionary for frame class why I passed `Home` class in showframe `self.show_frame(Home)`  instead of dictionary name `self.show_frame(frames[Home])` ?

Comment: See, show_frame has to take an argument , process that argument  and then, show it. Now, it has to iterate. Thus, you could use a  a list or a dictionary. If a list is used, Then, you have to use an integer index, and it will becometidious. Therefor, I used a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you need to create an instance of `Culpture`. You need to use that instance to call `show_frame`. When you do that, the instance will be automatically passed as the `self` parameter, and the argument you pass will be `frame_name`.

```
culpture = Culpture(root)
...
culpsure.show_frame(fsignin)
```

You didn't show where you create the instance of `Culpture` so it's hard to be any more specific than that.

Comment: Here showframe doesn't get reference of  'fsingin'. `class HomePage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        f1 = Culpture(parent)
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text="Homepage").grid()
        Button(self, text='SignIn', command=lambda: f1.showframe(fsignin), width=20).grid()`